# How can I calibrate colors?

Tags: monitor, colors, system-settings, color-management

In System Settings -> Colors there is color panel but "calibrate" button is grey and I am unable to calibrate it by myself.

Answer (score 1):

This feature requires a supported color calibration device that looks similar to a webcamera and attaches to the screen to detect the colors

This comment on [How do I reset an ICC profile in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/522057/how-do-i-reset-an-icc-profile-in-ubuntu/522067#comment710167_522067) states:

> `sensor device` - [Example devices](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Delectronics&field-keywords=Pantone%20huey%20Pro) - Note though that you MUST check
>   which ones are supported by ArgyllCMS, the software behind "Color"
>   above.